# VB.NET - How do I use pictures from an external .resources file?

Tags: vb.net, image, resources

I would like to know how to use images that I have placed in an external .resources file. Long story short: my program is subjected to a lot of changes, while the images within it are only updated once a year. I figured I could make reduce the amount my users would need to download by storing these images into a binary resource file, so only the main executable needs to be re-downloaded. I generated this file using something like this:

```
Dim stream As System.IO.Stream
Dim rsxw As New System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter("MyData.resx")
stream = Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgram.File1.png")
Dim bmp = New Bitmap(stream)
stream.Close()
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = CType(bmp, System.Drawing.Image)
rsxw.AddResource(name, img)
bmp.Dispose()
img.Dispose()
rsxw.Close()
```

I then compiled the resulting resx file to a .resources file using ResGen. I would now like to use these images in my program.

I was initially doing something like this:

```
dim filename as string = "File1"
stream =Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgram." & filename & ".png")
picboximg = New Bitmap(stream)
stream.Close()
PreviewBox.Image = picboximg
```

But since the resources are no longer embedded, this method no longer works. How do I go about getting the images from this resource file now?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A slightly easier way is to create a DLL with the images in it as standard resources and provide a function to return the desired image either by name or some ID.  Does the same thing without have to create a special file or navigate assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [ResourceReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddth8hta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But there's no good reason to give up on the convenience and type-safety of My.Resources.  Simply add a class library project to your solution, call it (say) MyRes.  Click the Show All Files button in the Solution Explorer window toolbar.  Expand My Project and double-click Resources.resx.  On the toolbar, change the Access Modifier property to "Public".  Add resources like you normally do.  Add the project reference, you can now simply access the resources in this *separate* dll in your code.  For example:

```
    Me.BackgroundImage = MyRes.My.Resources.animation
```

Comment: Hi there! The reason I was using the streamreader is because the name I had would be coming from a variable. Is there a way of using My.Resources with a variable in the name? Also, with regards to your class library suggestion, do you mean I would have to create a class in a separate project, embed these resources in, then write a function to retrieve these images and pass it along?

Comment: MyRes.My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(whatever)